# Why was Akira naked in the first episode of Eden of the East?

Tags: eden-of-the-east

Why was Akira naked in the beginning of Eden of the East?

Supposedly it was revealed later on in the series. However, I wasn't able to pick it up despite having watched it through in depth.

Could someone provide a summary?

Comment: There's a few theories in [this forum thread](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?t=81186), but it doesn't appear that anyone actually *knows* why...

Answer (score 4):

A couple of theories on that.

1. He was trying to remove anything that could be used to identify him, which is why he erased his memories as well.
2. He was going to be in front of the white house holding a gun and not knowing who he is, the nakedness was to add on to making himself look insane.